Progress bar with file stream C#
Any help would be appreciated.
I'm not too advanced on this threading stuff. I'm trying to get a progress bar to work with a stream without using a for loop. Any ideas?
    private async void btnFileStream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Try these:
        string strBIGFile = @"C:\BigFile_x86_64.iso";
        string strFile2 = @"C:\Verify.txt";
        string strFile3 = @"C:\key.txt";


        IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(value => progressBar1.Value = value);
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = File.OpenRead(strBIGFile))
            {
                using (Stream Stream2 = File.OpenRead(strFile2))
                {
                    using (Stream Stream3 = File.OpenRead(strFile3))
                    {
                        long length = dataStream.Length;
                        progress.Report(((int)length));
                        ProcessFiles(dataStream, Stream2, Stream3);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }
}


This code doesn't make sense. The (int)(long) cast also doesn't make sense in this context. You usually divide the length of the file in 100 chunks and report progress on each chunk, but that would be done, presumably, in the ProcessFiles() method, to which you pass the IProgress delegate -- Streams provide async methods, BTW -- This looks like a WinForms app; add the tag, since it's relevant

100 chunks is just an indication, could 1,000 (provided that you set the Maximum value of the ProgressBar accordingly); you define the heuristic, depending on how smooth the progression should appear, and of course on how often you need to report progress (or, on how often you can do that, because it may impact the UI)

There are a few options.
The simplest is to just forward the progress to ProcessFiles and let that deal with it. But this might not be feasible if third party code is doing the actual bulk of the reading. Unless the library actually supports progress reporting.
Another option is to wrap Stream in a custom "ProgressStream" class that periodically reports progress as data is read. But the Stream class is rather large, so I would expect this to be rather challenging to do well.
Third option would be to use a timer to poll the .Position property of the stream. Do note that this is technically not thread safe since Stream is not thread safe, but the worst I expect is an incorrect value, and that might be fine for reporting progress. It would also makes the code a bit more complicated since the timer and reading need to share the same stream.
But do you really need real progress reporting for reading files? Perhaps an indeterminate progress bar would be sufficient? How much data are you reading, and how does the speed compare against the theoretical speed of your disk? If you are storing/reading very large amounts of data, perhaps you could store that data in some smarter way to avoid needing to read it all in once? In my experience, local file access is rarely slow enough to warrant progress reporting.

Thank you for your reply.
The idea is just to give the user a graphical interface for the progress of a file being validated or created. Some files may be as big as an ISO and others a few megabytes. The files that would be created would not be that large it's just the files that are being verified as authentic. As I stated earlier not too familiar with threatening and adding progress bars. Although I dabble in C# (Windows forms) I'm definitely far from being an expert. :-)
